# Get the number after string with search result python

Tags: python

I want to search for the citation using below query. After searching,  I print it, it shows the results with nested list. And I want to get the number after 'citedby'.

If I copy the result and store it in variable,the program works. But if I directly store in the variable, the program doesn't work. Please help me to get the number after citation and store it into DB. And the number is changing every time.Help friends. I am new to python. Attached the search result below.

[image: Image shows the output]

```
 #!C:/Python27/python  
 from os import *  
 from cgi import *  
 import scholarly
 import re
 print "content-type: text/html\n\n" 

 search_query = scholarly.search_pubs_query('Three options for citation tracking: Google Scholar, Scopus and Web of Science')
 author = next(search_query).fill()
 print author
 lst = author
 if lst.has_key("citedby"):
     print lst['citedby']
```

Comment: What does `author` look like? Please give an example of the contents of the variable.

Comment: Variable have the search result sir.It shows in the picture.are you want in string format?

Comment: Can you show what this prints out: `print(author)`

Comment: That's the image shows the author variable sir.I stored which author have the search result sir.If i print author its also the same result sir.author and lst both variables are same sir

Comment: Ok, so can you now show what this prints out: `print(author['citedby'])`

Comment: No sir.It shows error

Comment: Sorry sir.It shows an empty page

Comment: Ok try this one just to rule it out `print(author[0]['citedby'])`

Comment: Sir this is also shows an empty page.I dont't know y.if we store the search result in author variable,it works.But now can't be working.What's the problem sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `author` object in this case is not a dictionary, nor list, but a `scholarly.Publication` object. This is because you have used the search_*pubs*_query `scholarly` method. So you can just reference its attribute.

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scholarly
>>> search_query = scholarly.search_pubs_query('Three options for citation     tracking: Google Scholar, Scopus and Web of Science')
>>> author = next(search_query).fill()
>>> type(author)
<class 'scholarly.Publication'>
>>> vars(author).keys()  # builtin vars will return a dictionary, so just show the keys
dict_keys(['bib', 'source', 'citedby', 'id_scholarcitedby', 'url_scholarbib', '_filled'])
>>> author.citedby
473
```

If you want an author, then you'll need to use `scholarly.search_author`.